# Anyone knows the inner working of select knob in React Storybook's Knobs addon?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, storybook, react-redux-form

I developed a React component in Typescript for conditional text search, looking like this:

[image]

Storybook select knob works correctly:
[image]

Storybook codes to make it happened:

```
<FilterComponentnt
                ...props
                accountNameTextCompareMethod={ConvertTextOptionItem(select('Account name search options', ['Starts with', 'Contains', 'Equals', 'Ends with'], 'Starts with'))}
                                    
                    />
```

Prop **accountNameTextCompareMethod** is of **enum** type:

```
export enum TextCompareMethod {
            StartsWith = 0,
            Contains = 1,
            EndsWith = 2,
            Equals = 3
        }
```

And the function **ConvertTextOptionItem** gets the string selected from the **select** Knob and convert it to enum **TextCompareMethod**; this works correctly as you saw in the picture 2

But when I used the component in the real app (in a container) and tried to set the same component prop accountNameTextCompareMethod via setting state:

```
const [accountNameCompareMethod, setAccountNameCompareMethod] = useState<TextCompareMethod>(props.accountNameTextCompareMethod ?? TextCompareMethod.StartsWith);

<FilterComponentnt
                ...props
                accountNameTextCompareMethod={accountNameCompareMethod} 
     ... />
```

Now it has no effect and the component's icon won't change as it was in storybook (picture 2).

My question is: How does the storybook **Knob select** work to set the same component prop successfully but my setting it from the real use of the same component (in a Redux form) does not? What did I do wrong and/or what the Storybook **select** knob did right?

Thanks for your time.

## Update

```
const ConvertTextOptionItem = (item: string): TextCompareMethod => {
  switch (item.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'startswith':
    case 'starts with':
      return TextCompareMethod.StartsWith;
    case 'endswith':
    case 'ends with':
      return TextCompareMethod.EndsWith;
    case 'contains':
    case 'contain':
      return TextCompareMethod.Contains;
    case 'equals':
    case 'equal':
      return TextCompareMethod.Equals;
    default:
      return TextCompareMethod.StartsWith;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include `ConvertTextOptionItem` so we may see what it does? Can you also share what the value of `props.accountNameTextCompareMethod` that is passed to the `useState` hook and a confirmation of the `accountNameCompareMethod` value being passed to `accountNameTextCompareMethod` prop?

Comment: `const **ConvertTextOptionItem** = (item: string): TextCompareMethod => {
   switch (item.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'startswith':
    case 'starts with':
     return TextCompareMethod.StartsWith;
    case 'endswith':
    case 'ends with':
     return TextCompareMethod.EndsWith;
    case 'contains':
    case 'contain':
     return TextCompareMethod.Contains;
    case 'equals':
    case 'equal':
     return TextCompareMethod.Equals;
    default:
     return TextCompareMethod.StartsWith;
   }
  };
 '

Comment: Regarding your question if the props.accountNameTextCompareMethod that is passed to the useState hook, yes, the value is passed and I can see it in console.log(). The puzzle was that when assigning it (accountNameCompareMethod) to the component prop **accountNameTextCompareMethod**, it has no effect. But setting it from storybook **select** knob does.